# How to escape spaces on Windows path in autocmd?

Tags: autocmd, microsoft-windows

I use the following `autocmd` to generate a template for markdown files in Vim.

```
au BufNewFile C:/my_dir/*.md :silent 0r !C:/my_dir/template.py '%'
```

Our IT department now forced me to move my files to a path where the folder name has spaces: `C:/my new path/`

How can I escape those spaces in the `autocmd`?

I tried escaping them with back slashes and adding single or double quotes, but it did not work:

```
au BufNewFile 'C:/my\ new\ path/*.md' :silent 0r !'C:/my\ new\ path/template.py' '%'
```

Comment: It's not as if Vim was the only program that can trip on spaces in paths. I'd probably raise a ticket for IT just out of spite.

Comment: @Friedrich A previous employer had a OneDrive folder with not only spaces and a dash in its name, but also an `æ`. I hated that drive with a passion, and IT refused to change it (something about it being too late, and too much already depended on that name). Sure, I had that letter on my keyboard, but as we all know, character encoding outside of ASCII is finicky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do:

```
au BufNewFile C:/my\ new\ path/*.md :silent 0r !"C:/my new path/template.py"
```

You need to escape the space in the pattern (and avoid to quote it)

The path could contains spaces but needs to be in double quotes.

Comment: I was able to make it work, but I had to add double quotes to the command like this:
`au BufNewFile C:/my\ new\ path/*.md :silent 0r !"C:/my new path/template.py"`
I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have accepted your edit :-)